# JTextArea - setText() and append() not working in Listener method()

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

As the title says i have a JList on the left side and a JTextArea on the right.

I set up my listener for the JList in the makeTextPanel() method like this:

```
listSelectionModel = list.getSelectionModel();
listSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(this);
```

where the method being called on the action event is:

```
//This method is required by ListSelectionListener.
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("HEY");
    textArea.setText(null);
    textArea.setText("1: \n");
    textArea.append("2: \n");
    textArea.append("3: \n");
    textArea.append("4: \n");
    }
```

The event happens because in the terminal i can see "HEY" but nothing gets printed to the textarea. If i try to print to the textarea in the makeTextPanel() method after creating the textarea then it will print. What is wrong? Why wont it print in the event method valueChanged? I would really appreciate it if someone could take a look at see what i am missing here.

Full code:

Comment: There is an `error` in your code. I can't compile it.

Comment: edited the code, it was the public constructor's name. I still dont know what is wrong with the textarea though

Answer (score 5):

It is working as per your code. You have declared `textArea` and `JList` globally so these two will only hold latest instances that is the instances you created while making `edit` tab. so if you see the edit tab your `textArea` will be having that text you set in the method.

you have to keep different instances of `textArea` and `List` for all your tabs and then only it will produce desired behavior.

Hope this helps.